# Python concurrent executor.map() and submit()

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrency, submit, threadpoolexecutor

I'm learning how to use concurrent with `executor.map()` and `executor.submit()`.

I have a list that contains 20 url and want to send 20 requests at the same time, the problem is `.submit()` returns results in different order than the given list from the beginning. I've read that `map()` does what I need but i don't know how to write code with it.

The code below worked perfect to me.

Questions: is there any code block of `map()`that equivalent to the code below, or any sorting methods that can sort the result list from `submit()` by order of the list given?

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the map version of your existing code. Note that the callback now accepts a tuple as a parameter. I added an try\except in the callback so the results will not throw an error. The results are ordered according to the input list.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://www.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(tt):  # (url,timeout)
    url, timeout = tt
    try:
      with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
         return (url, conn.read())
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error:", url, ex)
        return(url,"")  # error, return empty string

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map(load_url, [(u,60) for u in URLS])  # pass url and timeout as tuple to callback
    executor.shutdown(wait=True) # wait for all complete
    print("Results:")
for r in results:  # ordered results, will throw exception here if not handled in callback
    print('   %r page is %d bytes' % (r[0], len(r[1])))
```

Output

```
Error: http://www.wsj.com/ HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Results:
   'http://www.foxnews.com/' page is 320028 bytes
   'http://www.cnn.com/' page is 1144916 bytes
   'http://www.wsj.com/' page is 0 bytes
   'http://www.bbc.co.uk/' page is 279418 bytes
   'http://some-made-up-domain.com/' page is 64668 bytes
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this worked as well , needed to change a bit to fit with my script.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the `map` method, you can use `enumerate` to build the `future_to_url` dict with not just the URLs as values, but also their indices in the list. You can then build a dict from the `future` objects returned by the call to `concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)` with indices as the keys, so that you can iterate an index over the length of the dict to read the dict in the same order as the corresponding items in the original list:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {
        executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): (i, url) for i, url in enumerate(URLS)
    }
    futures = {}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        i, url = future_to_url[future]
        futures[i] = url, future
    for i in range(len(futures)):
        url, future = futures[i]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```